# Banana Pi + Android + Touchscreen

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, touchscreen

I am looking at doing a small build for a project, however before buying all the hardware I just wanted to know if what I'm attempting is even possible?

I am looking at using the Banana Pi M2+ to run Android Oreo with a TFT Touchscreen (Made for Raspberry Pi). The main concerns I have are these:

- Will the Banana Pi M2+ be able to run the latest version of Android? (I found the min reqs. and it seems to meet them)
- Will I be able to install drivers for Android to recognise the Pi Touchscreen?

Many thanks in advance!

Paddy